# UITableView create 4 square

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to create calendar view with UITableView

I want  to have 4 square in each rows like the below picture:

would you please help me, how can I have 4 square in one row in table
I know how can I create dynamic table view with different sections and rows but how can i have 4 square in one row?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit1 : My code in viewDidLoad :**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *contents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSString *monKey = @"Monday";
NSString *tueKey = @"Tuesday";
NSString *wedKey = @"Wednday";
NSString *thuKey = @"Thusday";
NSString *friKey = @"Friday";
NSString *satKey = @"Satuarday";
NSString *sunKey = @"Sunnday";

[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Work Time", @"Absence", nil] forKey:monKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", @"Absence", nil] forKey:wedKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:tueKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:thuKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:friKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:satKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:sunKey];

[keys addObject:tueKey];
[keys addObject:monKey];
[keys addObject:wedKey];
[keys addObject:thuKey];
[keys addObject:friKey];
[keys addObject:satKey];
[keys addObject:sunKey];



[self setSectionKeys:keys];
[self setSectionContents:contents];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
target:self action:@selector(addNewItem)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
}
```

**My Code in cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; 
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

int column = 4;
for (int i=0; i<column; i++) {

    UIImageView *aBackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32+184*i,10, 167,215)];
    aBackgroundImageView.tag = (column*indexPath.row)+i;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:aBackgroundImageView];
   // [aBackgroundImageView release];
}
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease]; 
    }
   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
int column = 4;

   for (int i=0; i<column; i++) {

        UIImageView *aBackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32+184*i,10, 167,215)];
        aBackgroundImageView.tag = (column*indexPath.row)+i;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:aBackgroundImageView];
        [aBackgroundImageView release];
    }
  return cell;
}
```

Column will number of items you want in one cell.

Comment: it saids use of undeclared identifier

Comment: just put int column = 4 above this code piece in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. 4 is for the number of columns you want to put in a single row in your tableview.

Comment: That should just be the cell identifier. Make sure the string you pass to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is defined, i.e. `static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellId"; UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];`

Comment: @ErenBeşel rightnow I don't have any error but how can I test it since I don't have any thing in my cell when I run the programm

Comment: @ErenBeşel should I pul somthing in my viewDidLoad ?

Comment: Yeah, you can add some `NSStrings` objects into the array you specified as the datasource for the tableview in `numberOfRowsInSection`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a calendar view, check out [this code](https://github.com/evolvIQ/iqwidgets/blob/master/IQCalendarView.m) for some ideas (depending on what you want to achieve).

To create a `UITableView` row with four equally sized cells, just implement the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` datasource method to create a view with e.g. four equally sized `UILabel`s.

Comment: would you please let me know with sample that How can I create 4 cell in one row in uitableview I don't know How should I do hat

Comment: Each row in the `UITableView` is a cell. You can not have multiple cells per row, but each cells can contain any number of views. Just use `addSubview:` to add multiple views to each cell (=row).