# cell specification in uitableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITableView create 4 square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718414/uitableview-create-4-square)

I want to have 4 cell in one row in uiTableview but nothing appear, I don't know why would you please help me 
this a the picture for cell

Thanks in advance

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *contents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSString *monKey = @"Monday";
NSString *tueKey = @"Tuesday";
NSString *wedKey = @"Wednday";
NSString *thuKey = @"Thusday";
NSString *friKey = @"Friday";
NSString *satKey = @"Satuarday";
NSString *sunKey = @"Sunnday";

[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Work Time", @"Absence", nil] forKey:monKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", @"Absence", nil] forKey:wedKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:tueKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:thuKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:friKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:satKey];
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Compensation", @"Work Time", nil] forKey:sunKey];

[keys addObject:tueKey];
[keys addObject:monKey];
[keys addObject:wedKey];
[keys addObject:thuKey];
[keys addObject:friKey];
[keys addObject:satKey];
[keys addObject:sunKey];



[self setSectionKeys:keys];
[self setSectionContents:contents];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
target:self action:@selector(addNewItem)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
}
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; 
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

int column = 4;
for (int i=0; i<column; i++) {

    UIImageView *aBackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32+184*i,10, 167,215)];
    aBackgroundImageView.tag = (column*indexPath.row)+i;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:aBackgroundImageView];
   // [aBackgroundImageView release];
}
return cell;
}
```

**Edit 1**

this is the picture when I added this line

```
 aBackgroundImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

**Edit 2 :
with Rog method**

[image]

Comment: @dasdom but with diffrent error I need the answer

Comment: With the same question asked several times you wont increase the quality of the answers. When the answers don't help try to improve your question.

Comment: @dasdom this is the whole thing that I have would you please help me , I just want to have 4 button or 4 picture or 4 cell in on row of table

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that in:

```
for (int i=0; i<column; i++) {

  UIImageView *aBackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32+184*i,10, 167,215)];
  aBackgroundImageView.tag = (column*indexPath.row)+i;
  [cell.contentView addSubview:aBackgroundImageView];
  // [aBackgroundImageView release];
}
```

you are not providing a content for your views...

so that should explain why you don't see anything... Try adding:

```
aBackgroundImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

and see if anything changes.

Comment: I added the picture that I have

Comment: do you know how can I put space between my column?

Comment: well, you have Rog's sample to set correctly the frame of your cells. Change `cell.contentView.size.height` into `cell.contentView.frame.size.height`. Furthermore, on the second line, it is `aView`, not `aview`!!

Answer (score 0):

Your method is a bit of a mess. Your main problem is how you are setting the frame origin for the UIImageView instances as they are 1) too big for the cell 2) out of the cell bounds.

Try this (ps: there may be typos as I've written it off the top of my head):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    int numberOfColumns = 4;
    CGSize gridSize = CGSizeMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width / numberOfColumns, cell.contentView.frame.size.height / 2); // Height size is arbitrary here, width is obtained by dividing total width by number of columns
    for (int i=0; i < column; i++) 
    {
         UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(gridSize.width * i, cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2 - gridSize.height/2, gridSize.width, gridSize.height)];
         aview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1/i+1]; // This is just so you can see the different gridCells within the cell
         [cell.contentView addSubview:aView];
         [aView release];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I got an error I put it in edit would you please check it

Answer (score 0):

Here i create the one demo  application like you want and that some of the code put into here.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSUInteger devide=[self.tableArray count] / 3;

    if ([self.tableArray count] % 3 &gt;0 ) {

        devide+=1;

    } else {

        devide=devide;

    }
    return devide;
}
```

And cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        UIButton *imgV1=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        UIButton *imgV2=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        UIButton *imgV3=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:3];
        [imgV1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [imgV2 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [imgV3 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        HJManagedImageV *img1=[[HJManagedImageV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgV1.frame.size.width, imgV1.frame.size.height)];
        HJManagedImageV *img2=[[HJManagedImageV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgV2.frame.size.width, imgV2.frame.size.height)];
        HJManagedImageV *img3=[[HJManagedImageV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgV3.frame.size.width, imgV3.frame.size.height)];
        img1.tag=img2.tag=img3.tag=10000;

        img1.backgroundColor=img2.backgroundColor=img3.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [imgV1 addSubview:img1];
        [imgV2 addSubview:img2];
        [imgV3 addSubview:img3];
    }

    int x=indexPath.row;
    x=x*3;

    UIButton *imgV1=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UIButton *imgV2=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UIButton *imgV3=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:3];

    HJManagedImageV *img1=(HJManagedImageV*)[imgV1 viewWithTag:10000];
    HJManagedImageV *img2=(HJManagedImageV*)[imgV2 viewWithTag:10000];
    HJManagedImageV *img3=(HJManagedImageV*)[imgV3 viewWithTag:10000];

    [img1 clear];
    [img2 clear];
    [img3 clear];

    [imgV1 setTitle:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    img1.url=[NSURL URLWithString:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x]];
    [img1 showLoadingWheel];
    [GlobalCacheManager manage:img1];

    if((x+1) &gt;= self.tableArray.count){
        imgV2.hidden=imgV3.hidden=YES;
        [imgV2 setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [imgV3 setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else if( (x+2)&gt;=self.tableArray.count) {
        img2.url=[NSURL URLWithString:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x+1]];
        [img2 showLoadingWheel];
        [GlobalCacheManager manage:img2];
        imgV1.hidden=imgV2.hidden=YES;
        imgV3.hidden=YES;
        [imgV2 setTitle:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x+1] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        [imgV3 setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [img2 showLoadingWheel];
        [img3 showLoadingWheel];
        img2.url=[NSURL URLWithString:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x+1]];
        [GlobalCacheManager manage:img2];
        img3.url=[NSURL URLWithString:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x+2]];
        [GlobalCacheManager manage:img3];
        imgV2.hidden=imgV3.hidden=NO;
        [imgV2 setTitle:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x+1] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        [imgV3 setTitle:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x+2] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Also You can download the sample code from http://bit.ly/T1Cy0N hope this helping to you